# Placeholder in rails simpleform association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How to put placeholder in rails simpleform association. I have tried a different ways but nothing works for me. The target code is:

```
<%= f.association :sex, :include_blank => true  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Select2, you can [include placeholders in select elements](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#placeholders). The requirement is to include a blank element as first item and you can include the placeholder text as a data HTML attribute.

[image: Example result]

In your case:

```
<%= f.association :sex, include_blank: true, 
                        data: { placeholder: 'Search...'}  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the simple_form.rb in initializers

You can find something below

```
 # Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
 SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  .
  .
  .
  config.wrappers :default, :class => :input, :hint_class => :field_with_hint, :error_class => :field_with_errors do |b|
## Extensions enabled by default
  # Calculates placeholders automatically from I18n
  # You can also pass a string as f.input :placeholder => "Placeholder"
  b.use :placeholder 
  .
  .
  end
 end
```

so it is depends on translational  file

So you need to do for `user` model `sex` attribute

```
 en:
   simple_form:
     placeholders:
        user:
          sex:
```

As placeholder works for `input`

Then you try this

```
  <% f.association :user do |u| %>
    <%= u.input :sex %>
  <% end %>
```

And  It should work

Comment: Why they call it `sex` when they want to say `gender`? ;)

Comment: It works well for input fields, but for association still doesn't.

Comment: `<% f.association :user do |u| %>
    <%= u.input :sex %>
 <% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

Using Rails 5.0.0.beta2 and Simple Form 3.2.1, this works for me:

```
<%= f.association :strands,
                  collection: Strand.order(label: :asc),
                  include_blank: "-- Select strands --"
 %>
```

I had no luck using various permutations on `:prompt` and some of the other ideas that I found suggested here.

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= f.association :sex, :include_blank => true, placeholder: "sex" %>
```

Comment: try this  <%= f.association :sex, :include_blank => true,input_html: {'data-placeholder' => 'sex'} %>

Comment: Place holder isn't an attribute of select elements, and it doesn't work in Rails 5 / Simple Form 3.2.1